# dxDataGrid on row tab

Tags: javascript, html, devextreme

I am trying to implement a devextreme example.
http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/data_grid-master-detail-master-detail_api

In this example I want to implement two things.

1.when user tabs on a particular data row then only it should display the    details,otherwise it should display a normal grid.

2.Instated of notes i want to display a list through my webapi service .

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.when user tabs on a particular data row then only it should display the details,otherwise it should display a normal grid.

In this example, row activates in [onContentReady](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/?version=15_2#onContentReady). You can remove onContentReady function in [this example](http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/data_grid-master-detail-master-detail_api), and it will display a normal grid. Also you can read more about [master detail](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/masterDetail/).

> 2.Instated of notes i want to display a list through my webapi service .

You can use [datasource](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Layer/DataSource/) option. Also you can read more about [data layer](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Data_Layer/Data_Layer/?version=15_2#Data_Layer_Data_Layer_Creating_DataSource_From_url)